# Unable to create a constant value of type 'WebApplication2.Models.Role'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var userToEdit = _db.AuthLogin.Where(user => user.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
    if (userToEdit == null)
        return HttpNotFound();


    return View(new EditUser()
    {
        Email = userToEdit.Email,
        UserName = userToEdit.UserName,
        Password = userToEdit.Password,
        Roles = _db.Roles.Select(role => new RoleCheckBox
        {
            Id = role.Id,
            IsChecked = userToEdit.Roles.Contains(role),
            Name = role.Name
        }).ToList()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your `Role` class is defined, but you can try something like this:

```
    List<int> userRoleIds = userToEdit.Roles.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
    EditUser model = new EditUser()
    {
        Email = userToEdit.Email,
        UserName = userToEdit.UserName,
        Password = userToEdit.Password,
        Roles = _db.Roles.Select(role => new RoleCheckBox
        {
            Id = role.Id,
            IsChecked = userRoleIds.Contains(role.Id),
            Name = role.Name
        }).ToList()
    });
    return View(model);
```

or change

```
_db.Roles.Select(...)
```

to

```
_db.Roles.ToList().Select(...)
```